# FlatList with horizontal scroll and sticky column

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am looking for component where i can have multiple number of rows and columns. In which first column will be sticky and rest of columns will be scrolled horizontally as well as vertically. I have found solution in `reactJS` using `Table` but there is no way to do it with `FlatList`. If anyone have any idea or can guide me to right direction.

I have tried with multiple `ScrollView` but it did't work

```
<ScrollView>
    <ScrollView horizontal>

    </ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Above solution doesn't work as it is not scrolling vertically. And if i will add scroll for each row, it will not work for whole `FlatList`. I need something like [this example](https://codepen.io/paulobrien/pen/gWoVzN)

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233233/horizontal-scroll-some-part-of-listview-column) reference question but it's solution is to give horizontal scrollview to each row.

Answer (score 0):

Install the library `react-native-table-component`. Here is an example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Alert, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { Table, TableWrapper,Col, Cols, Cell } from 'react-native-table-component';

export default class ExampleFive extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const elementButton = (value) => (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._alertIndex(value)}>
        <View style={styles.btn}>
          <Text style={styles.btnText}>{value}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );

    this.state = {
      tableTitle: ['Left Column', 'Left Column', 'Left Column', 'Left Column'],
      tableData: [
        [elementButton('Header 2'), 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        [elementButton('Header 3'), '1', '2', '3', '4'],
        [elementButton('Header 4'), 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        [elementButton('Header 5'), 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        [elementButton('Header 6'), 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        [elementButton('Header 7'), 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        [elementButton('Header 8'), 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        [elementButton('Header 9'), 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
      ]
    }
  }

  _alertIndex(value) {
    Alert.alert(`This is column ${value}`);
  }

  render() {
    const state = this.state;
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <Table style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          {/* Left Wrapper */}
          <TableWrapper style={{width: 80}}>
            <Cell data="" style={styles.singleHead}/>
            <TableWrapper style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              <Col data={state.tableTitle} style={styles.title} heightArr={[30, 30, 30, 30]} textStyle={styles.titleText}></Col>
            </TableWrapper>
          </TableWrapper>

          {/* Right Wrapper */}
          <ScrollView horizontal>
          <TableWrapper style={{}}>
            <Cols data={state.tableData} heightArr={[40, 30, 30, 30, 30]} textStyle={styles.text}/>
          </TableWrapper>
          </ScrollView>
        </Table>
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, padding: 16, paddingTop: 30, backgroundColor: '#fff' },
  singleHead: { width: 80, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#c8e1ff' },
  title: { backgroundColor: '#f6f8fa' },
  titleText: { textAlign:'center' },
  text: { textAlign: 'center' },
  btn: { width: 58, height: 18, marginHorizontal: 7, backgroundColor: '#c8e1ff', borderRadius: 2, justifyContent: "center" },
  btnText: { textAlign: 'center' }
});
```

Check this code in expo for demo: https://snack.expo.io/rJ2mE1eBE

#### UPDATE:

Replace `<View>` with `<ScollView>` on parent of `<Table />` component.

Comment: It's not scrolling vertically

Comment: @RaviRupareliya I have update my answer. Replace parent of table component with ScrollView

Comment: Its scrolling horizontaly only, if i put ScrollView it is scrolling whole screen, i want fixed header and fixes first column